# Can we pass html content to monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

We have a requirement to highlight parts of the content inside monaco editor, can anyone give some direction on this?

I want to parse monaco code content and change part of it into html, or use  to underline it, but it seemed monaco only treat that as pure text.

Is this doable or not doable at all?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these fiddle helps you?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.25.2/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css">

    <style>
      html,
      body {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #1e1e1e;
      }



      .sql-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #sql-editor {
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <template id="tmp">
<style>
    #test1 {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #test2 {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #test3 {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
<div id="test1">asdasdasd</div>
<div id="test2">sdfsdf,</div>
<div id="test3">nm,bm,nb</div>
<script>
    let a = function(){
        let b = 1;
        let c = 2;
      }
</script>
    </template>
    <div id="sql-editor" class="sql-container"></div>

    <script>
      var require = {
        paths: {
          'vs': 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.25.2/min/vs'
        }
      };

    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.25.2/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.25.2/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.25.2/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@0.25.2/min/vs/base/worker/workerMain.js"></script>
    <script>
      var createEditor = function(language, elementId) {
        var h_div = document.getElementById(elementId);
        return monaco.editor.create(h_div, {
          value: [
            ''
          ].join('\n'),
          language: language,
          theme: 'vs-dark',
          lineNumbers: "on",
          roundedSelection: false,
          scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
          ariaLabel: "online code editor",
          accessibilityHelpUrl: "Nothing yet...",
          readOnly: false,
          scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
          minimap: {
            enabled: false
          },
          scrollbar: {
            // Subtle shadows to the left & top. Defaults to true.
            useShadows: false,

            // Render vertical arrows. Defaults to false.
            verticalHasArrows: true,
            // Render horizontal arrows. Defaults to false.
            horizontalHasArrows: true,

            // Render vertical scrollbar.
            // Accepted values: 'auto', 'visible', 'hidden'.
            // Defaults to 'auto'
            vertical: 'hidden',
            // Render horizontal scrollbar.
            // Accepted values: 'auto', 'visible', 'hidden'.
            // Defaults to 'auto'
            horizontal: 'auto',

            verticalScrollbarSize: 17,
            horizontalScrollbarSize: 17,
            arrowSize: 30
          }
        });
      }
      var editor = createEditor('sql', 'sql-editor');
      var setEditor = function(type, content) {
        editor.setValue(content);
        editor.render();
        monaco.editor.setModelLanguage(editor.getModel(), type);
      }
      let htmlContent = document.getElementById('tmp').innerHTML;
      setEditor('html', htmlContent);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```